# Elasticsearch replace special characters

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I want replace lithuanian characters to latin characters:

```
 analysis:
                        char_filter :
                            lt_characters :
                                type : mapping,
                                mappings : ['ą' => 'a','Ą' => 'a','č' => 'c','Č' => 'c','ę' => 'e','Ę' => 'e','ė' => 'e','Ė' => 'e','į' => 'i','Į' => 'i','š' => 's','Š' => 's','ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','ū' => 'u','ž' => 'z']
```

But something went wrong, I think elasticsearch not understand my characters, I get error:

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/local/bin/php54-cli app/console fos:elastica:populate



  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Cannot import resource "/home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/app/config/config.yml" from "/home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml". (Unexpected characters ( => 'a','Ą' => 'a','č' => 'c','Č' => 'c','ę' => 'e','Ę' => 'e','ė' => 'e','Ė' => 'e','į' => 'i','Į' => 'i','š' => 's','Š' => 's','ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','ū' => 'u','ž' => 'z']) at line 86 (near "mappings : ['ą' => 'a','Ą' => 'a','č' => 'c','Č' => 'c','ę' => 'e','Ę' => 'e','ė' => 'e','Ė' => 'e','į' => 'i','Į' => 'i','š' => 's','Š' => 's','ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','ū' => 'u','ž' => 'z']").)  






  [Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Unexpected characters ( => 'a','Ą' => 'a','č' => 'c','Č' => 'c','ę' => 'e','Ę' => 'e','ė' => 'e','Ė' => 'e','į' => 'i','Į' => 'i','š' => 's','Š' => 's','ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','ū' => 'u','ž' => 'z']) at line 86 (near "mappings : ['ą' => 'a','Ą' => 'a','č' => 'c','Č' => 'c','ę' => 'e','Ę' => 'e','ė' => 'e','Ė' => 'e','į' => 'i','Į' => 'i','š' => 's','Š' => 's','ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','Ų' => 'u','ū' => 'u','ž' => 'z']").
```

How to solve this problem with replacments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch would understand this:

`"analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "lt_characters": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "ą=>a",
            "Ą=>a",
            "č=>c",
            "Č=>c",
            "ę=>e",
            "Ę=>e",
            "ė=>e",
            "Ė=>e",
            "į=>i",
            "Į=>i",
            "š=>s",
            "Š=>s",
            "ų=>u",
            "Ų=>u",
            "ū=>u",
            "ž=>z"
          ]
        }
      }`

You don't have to put each character between quotes, but the entire mapping: `"ą=>a"`.

Comment: how can I do this in reverse mode? for example ("α=>ά","α=>α") ?

Comment: what if i use FOS ELASTICA ?